# Teams notification do have custom permissions?

Tags: node.js, electron, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

How Teams notification works, its display in custom templates, and also it's not listing in windows notification senders list(Notification and Actions), also its popup stay on the screen up to 10 seconds and default windows notification stay up to 5 seconds depends on the Ease center setting.

Comment: Teams uses a browserWindow with custom HTML & CSS for notifications.

Comment: Could you please post it to [product support channel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/feedback#product-support-channels)